# How can i add a vertical column divider in Material-ui table

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I have created a table of given height (say 70vh). I want a vertical Column divider for the whole height of the table. I can add it using CSS for TableCell. But i want that the verticle column divider should be there even if i don't have any TableCell.

```
import React from "react";

//MUI Stuffs
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tableContainer: {
    maxWidth: "150vh",
    margin: "auto",
    marginTop: "15vh",
    height: "70vh",
    background: "#ccffff",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderStyle: "solid",
  },
  tableCell: {
    borderRightStyle: "solid",
    borderRightColor: "black",
  },
  tableHead: {
    borderBottomStyle: "solid",
    borderBottomColor: "blue",
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
  },
}));

function Canvas() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const cols = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"];
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper} className={classes.tableContainer}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead className={classes.tableHead}>
          <TableRow>
            {cols.map((col) => (
              <TableCell align="center" className={classes.tableCell}>
                {col}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow></TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default Canvas;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code? or give more details.

Comment: I have shared the code

Comment: I did not understand this sentence. (But i want that the verticle column divider should be there even if i don't have any TableCell.) Please explain in detail

Comment: As u can see in the image... In header section, i'm having a TableCell (Col1,Col2..... here). I'm having the lines between them as I have added CSS on TableCell. But the body of the table is empty so no verticle lines are there! In short i just have divide the columns with vertical lines

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do something like this by not using `TableHeader`:
[image]

I added a `height` to table of `70vh` so it's the same height as the container. Then I changed the display type of `tableCell` to be `tableRowGroup` which allows the columns to flexibly fill the available space. I've removed `TableHead` completely because MUI is forcing the CSS display of `table-header-group` which isn't expanding to fill the table space.

```
import React from "react";

//MUI Stuffs
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tableContainer: {
    maxWidth: "150vh",
    margin: "auto",
    marginTop: "15vh",
    height: "70vh",
    background: "#ccffff",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderStyle: "solid"
  },
  table: {
    height: "70vh"
  },
  tableCell: {
    borderRightStyle: "solid",
    borderRightColor: "black",
    display: "tableRowGroup"
  }
}));

function Canvas() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const cols = ["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"];
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper} className={classes.tableContainer}>
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableRow>
          {cols.map((col) => (
            <TableCell align="center" className={classes.tableCell}>
              {col}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            {cols.map((col) => (
              <TableCell align="center" className={classes.tableCell}>
                {col}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}

export default Canvas;
```

You can remove the `TableRow` in the `TableBody` to see that the header row does in fact fill all the available space.

Comment: edited bc TableHeader was not playing well with `tableRowGroup`

Comment: But the TableHead is taking whole space! I just want the header to be at top and the horizontal line to the height of the table